# Quitar espacios en archivo txt con visual basic

Tags: vba, visual, basic

Hola tengo este codigo

```
Sub ExportarFileTxt()
Ruta = "C:\Users\eperez\OneDrive - ejemploArchivo.txt"

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 17).End(xlUp).Row

Open Ruta For Output As #1

For i = 2 To lastrow

Print #1, Cells(i, 17).Value
    
Next i

Close #1

MsgBox "Archivo Generado"

End Sub
```

Este código me genera un archivo txt con las datos que necesito, pero me genera los datos con un espacio adicional al final, por ejemplo:

```
dato1
dato2
dato3
dato4
dato5
dato6
dato7
       <----- Aqui hay un espacio en blanco y quiero quitarlo para que termine al lado del dato7
```

Necesito quitar el espacio en blanco y que el archivo termine en el dato 7 sin ningún espacio por debajo de este ¿Como lo puedo hacer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por el ejemplo que has puesto, me parece que es VBA. Si es visual basic normal, la solución es parecida.

Según https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/printstatement, si pones un ; (punto y coma) al final del print, no te va a saltar a la siguiente línea.

Tienes que mirar si estás en la última línea y hacer un print con punto y coma al final, o un print normal en otro caso.

Algo así (es un ejemplo hecho rápido,  puede tener errores de sintaxis)

```
For i = 2 To lastrow
If i < lastrow then
    Print #1, Cells(i, 17).Value
Else
     Print #1, Cells(i, 17).Value ;
End if
Next i
```

Otra opción es usar siempre el punto y coma, y hacer prints vacíos, excepto en la última línea:

```
Print #1, Cells(i, 17).Value ;
If i < lastrow then
    Print #1, ""
End if
```